# How to dynamically update a file name with increasing integers?

Tags: php

I want to update a file name so that it looks like this each time it is updated.

```
 some_name_1, some_name_2, some_name_3, etc.
```

Each update will increase the trailing integer by one.  Below is my prototype, I wanted to make sure this is the best practice way to do it, before implementing it.  Also, I'm not 100% PHP will do the implicit casting correctly.

Is this a good practice way to update a file name?

```
// ... in a class
private function updateFileName()
{
    $pattern = '#_(\d+)$#';
    $subject = $this->file_name; // $subject holds current file name
    preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
    if($matches[0])
    {
        $patterns = array();
        $temp = $matches[0];
        $patterns[0] = '/$temp$/';
        $replacements = array();
        $replacements[0] = $matches[0] + 1;
        preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $subject); // $subject now holds new name
    }
}
```

**Clarification**

- The file name is actually a hash, and is one string of characters.
- The _1, etc will always be at the end of the string ( perhaps good to use an anchor )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the whole thing in one preg_replace:

```
preg_replace("/\b([^\w]+)\b/i",'_',$filename);
```